# What is the word or phrasal verb that means "escort someone and tell him goodbye before letting him leave"?

Tags: vocabulary, idiomatic-language

What is the word or phrasal verb that means "escort someone and tell him goodbye before letting him leave"? Is there a way to say this in a more succinct way? By "escort someone and tell him goodbye before letting him leave", I mean when your friends comes to your house and then he leaves, and then you escort him in order to be polite and friendly to him.

Answer (score 1):

You might say you are going to "see him out"

> (see someone out) to go with someone to the door when they are leaving in order to say goodbye to them.
>
> *My secretary will see you out.*
>
> [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/see-out)

Comment: Or "show him to the door" (not that he doesn't know where the front door is, but out of politeness).